# Shopify web-hook topic, orders/create and customers/create, when someone creates account during order creation, which API web-hook will trigger first?

Tags: rest, shopify, webhooks, shopify-api

Question 1:
If someone creates an account during order creation, which API webhook will trigger first: "orders/create" or "customers/create"?

Question 2:
If someone creates an account during order creation, would there be a customer ID and email available in the order objects, specifically in the nested customer object?

```
// Occurs when an order is created. Subscription apps need to query the order's line items for their selling plan to determine whether this is a subscription order that they own.
{
  "id": 820982911946154508,
  "email": "jon@doe.ca",
  "closed_at": null,
  "created_at": "2022-10-03T12:55:00-04:00",
  "updated_at": "2022-10-03T12:55:00-04:00",
  "number": 234,
  "note": null,
  "token": "123456abcd",
  "gateway": null,
  "test": true,
  "total_price": "403.00",
  "subtotal_price": "393.00",
  "total_weight": 0,
  "total_tax": "0.00",
  "taxes_included": false,
  "currency": "USD",
  "financial_status": "voided",
  "confirmed": false,
  "total_discounts": "5.00",
  "total_line_items_price": "398.00",
  "cart_token": null,
  "buyer_accepts_marketing": true,
  "name": "#9999",
  "referring_site": null,
  "landing_site": null,
  "cancelled_at": "2022-10-03T12:55:00-04:00",
  "cancel_reason": "customer",
  "total_price_usd": null,
  "checkout_token": null,
  "reference": null,
  "user_id": null,
  "location_id": null,
  "source_identifier": null,
  "source_url": null,
  "processed_at": null,
  "device_id": null,
  "phone": null,
  "customer_locale": "en",
  "app_id": null,
  "browser_ip": null,
  "landing_site_ref": null,
  "order_number": 1234,
  "discount_applications": [
    {
      "type": "manual",
      "value": "5.0",
      "value_type": "fixed_amount",
      "allocation_method": "each",
      "target_selection": "explicit",
      "target_type": "line_item",
      "description": "Discount",
      "title": "Discount"
    }
  ],
  "discount_codes": [

  ],
  "note_attributes": [

  ],
  "payment_gateway_names": [
    "visa",
    "bogus"
  ],
  "processing_method": "",
  "checkout_id": null,
  "source_name": "web",
  "fulfillment_status": "pending",
  "tax_lines": [

  ],
  "tags": "",
  "contact_email": "jon@doe.ca",
  "order_status_url": "https:\/\/jsmith.myshopify.com\/548380009\/orders\/123456abcd\/authenticate?key=abcdefg",
  "presentment_currency": "USD",
  "total_line_items_price_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "398.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "398.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "total_discounts_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "5.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "5.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "total_shipping_price_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "10.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "10.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "subtotal_price_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "393.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "393.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "total_price_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "403.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "403.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "total_tax_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "0.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "0.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "line_items": [
    {
      "id": 866550311766439020,
      "variant_id": 808950810,
      "title": "IPod Nano - 8GB",
      "quantity": 1,
      "sku": "IPOD2008PINK",
      "variant_title": null,
      "vendor": null,
      "fulfillment_service": "manual",
      "product_id": 632910392,
      "requires_shipping": true,
      "taxable": true,
      "gift_card": false,
      "name": "IPod Nano - 8GB",
      "variant_inventory_management": "shopify",
      "properties": [

      ],
      "product_exists": true,
      "fulfillable_quantity": 1,
      "grams": 567,
      "price": "199.00",
      "total_discount": "0.00",
      "fulfillment_status": null,
      "price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "199.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "199.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        }
      },
      "total_discount_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "0.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "0.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        }
      },
      "discount_allocations": [

      ],
      "duties": [

      ],
      "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/LineItem\/866550311766439020",
      "tax_lines": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 141249953214522974,
      "variant_id": 808950810,
      "title": "IPod Nano - 8GB",
      "quantity": 1,
      "sku": "IPOD2008PINK",
      "variant_title": null,
      "vendor": null,
      "fulfillment_service": "manual",
      "product_id": 632910392,
      "requires_shipping": true,
      "taxable": true,
      "gift_card": false,
      "name": "IPod Nano - 8GB",
      "variant_inventory_management": "shopify",
      "properties": [

      ],
      "product_exists": true,
      "fulfillable_quantity": 1,
      "grams": 567,
      "price": "199.00",
      "total_discount": "5.00",
      "fulfillment_status": null,
      "price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "199.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "199.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        }
      },
      "total_discount_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "5.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "5.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        }
      },
      "discount_allocations": [
        {
          "amount": "5.00",
          "discount_application_index": 0,
          "amount_set": {
            "shop_money": {
              "amount": "5.00",
              "currency_code": "USD"
            },
            "presentment_money": {
              "amount": "5.00",
              "currency_code": "USD"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "duties": [

      ],
      "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/LineItem\/141249953214522974",
      "tax_lines": [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "fulfillments": [

  ],
  "refunds": [

  ],
  "total_tip_received": "0.0",
  "original_total_duties_set": null,
  "current_total_duties_set": null,
  "payment_terms": null,
  "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/Order\/820982911946154508",
  "shipping_lines": [
    {
      "id": 271878346596884015,
      "title": "Generic Shipping",
      "price": "10.00",
      "code": null,
      "source": "shopify",
      "phone": null,
      "requested_fulfillment_service_id": null,
      "delivery_category": null,
      "carrier_identifier": null,
      "discounted_price": "10.00",
      "price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "10.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "10.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        }
      },
      "discounted_price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "10.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "10.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        }
      },
      "discount_allocations": [

      ],
      "tax_lines": [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "billing_address": {
    "first_name": "Bob",
    "address1": "123 Billing Street",
    "phone": "555-555-BILL",
    "city": "Billtown",
    "zip": "K2P0B0",
    "province": "Kentucky",
    "country": "United States",
    "last_name": "Biller",
    "address2": null,
    "company": "My Company",
    "latitude": null,
    "longitude": null,
    "name": "Bob Biller",
    "country_code": "US",
    "province_code": "KY"
  },
  "shipping_address": {
    "first_name": "Steve",
    "address1": "123 Shipping Street",
    "phone": "555-555-SHIP",
    "city": "Shippington",
    "zip": "40003",
    "province": "Kentucky",
    "country": "United States",
    "last_name": "Shipper",
    "address2": null,
    "company": "Shipping Company",
    "latitude": null,
    "longitude": null,
    "name": "Steve Shipper",
    "country_code": "US",
    "province_code": "KY"
  },
  "customer": {
    "id": 115310627314723954,
    "email": "john@example.com",
    "accepts_marketing": false,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "orders_count": 0,
    "state": "disabled",
    "total_spent": "0.00",
    "last_order_id": null,
    "note": null,
    "verified_email": true,
    "multipass_identifier": null,
    "tax_exempt": false,
    "tags": "",
    "last_order_name": null,
    "currency": "USD",
    "phone": null,
    "accepts_marketing_updated_at": null,
    "marketing_opt_in_level": null,
    "sms_marketing_consent": null,
    "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/Customer\/115310627314723954",
    "default_address": {
      "id": 715243470612851245,
      "customer_id": 115310627314723954,
      "first_name": null,
      "last_name": null,
      "company": null,
      "address1": "123 Elm St.",
      "address2": null,
      "city": "Ottawa",
      "province": "Ontario",
      "country": "Canada",
      "zip": "K2H7A8",
      "phone": "123-123-1234",
      "name": "",
      "province_code": "ON",
      "country_code": "CA",
      "country_name": "Canada",
      "default": true
    }
  }
}
```